# SSIS - Data flow stuck at Execution Phase while using Attunity Oracle Source

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, ssis, oledb, attunity

I am using **Attunity Oracle** drivers to connect to Oracle Database on a remote server to retrieve data and dump into Excel File.
Everything works fine in Visual Studio BIDS. From VS I can connect directly to remote Oracle server and retrieve the data.

But when i deploy this ETL to my production server (64 Bit Windows Server 2008 & SQL Server 2012), ETL is always get stuck at Execution phase. After running for some time (20-30 mins), it gives following **warning** & still keeps running without giving any errors -

```
[SSIS.Pipeline] Information: The buffer manager detected that the system was low on virtual memory, but was unable to swap out any buffers. 0 buffers were considered and 0 were locked. 
Either not enough memory is available to the pipeline because not enough is installed, other processes are using it, or too many buffers are locked.
```

Some more info -

1. I have checked server memory, only 3GB is in use out of total 12GB.
2. I have already set SQL server to use max 8GB.
3. I am using SQL Server Agent job to run the ETL periodically every 15 mins.
4. I have tried stopping all other ETLs on the server and tried running this ETL through `Execute Package Utility` but still the result is same.
5. I am using a **date range in Oracle Query** to retrieve the data, **when the query for a particular date range does not return any data, ETL execution is always successful** !!.

Progress log (Execute Package Utility) -

[image]

Any pointers/suggestion ??

Hope I am able to describe the issue properly.

**Update (5/Mar/2014) -**

I tried reducing the amount of data I am retrieving, and the ETL was successful.
I have also set the `DefaultBufferSize` to 10 MB(Max size).
But if the query data is exceeding `DefaultBufferSize` then why the package is successful on my development machine but not on the server ??

Thanks,
Prateek

Comment: Hi,when you say " Everything works fine in Visual Studio BIDS" does that mena it is working on Development sever?

Comment: Have you try to connect to Oracle OLEDB Provider for Oracle,using instead of Attunity .To be honest i have never used attunity.This is a   sugestion

Comment: let me know is it useful

Comment: yeah. it works in my development machine (which have privileges to connect to Oracle server).

Comment: We are using Attunity because its faster than Oracle OLEDB provider. So i was hoping we could find a solution using Attunity itself. Thanks for your inputs anyway ...

Comment: Is SQL Server using all of 8G? (thats not much BTW). Is there any left for the OS and..... SSIS buffer to use?